# Exchange Webservice Managed API - Prevent double booking

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there a way to check if a certain time is booked in a users calendar?

This example finds all appointments created today:

```
        var items = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeCreated, DateTime.Today), new ItemView(100));
```

I am wondering how I would go about checking for booked times, so I do not double book a user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use EWS Availability Service: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232134(v=exchg.141).aspx